# How to filter different parameter using If Else (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I have different parameter and condition to be filter before executing a function.

For example: An email subject must contain `Emergency` and does not contain `hehe`. In the meantime, the text of the same email must contain `alert` and do not contain `haha` to execute a function.
[image]

Currently I'm just using a hard-coded `if else` to filter the request, but it can only process a single rules. What I want to achieve is all the rules will be parse before executing a function.

**My Py script (This script is just checking if the Email subject have "Consent" in it)**

```
import datetime
import email
import imaplib
import mailbox
import smtplib

while True:
    EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "xxx@gmail.com"
    PASSWORD = "xxx"

    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
    mail.list()
    mail.select('inbox')
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN")  # (ALL/UNSEEN)
    i = len(data[0].split())

    for x in range(i):
        latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
        result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        # result, email_data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
        # this might work to set flag to seen, if it doesn't already
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

        # Header Details
        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            local_message_date = "%s" % (str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
        email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
        email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
        subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

        # Body details
        for part in email_message.walk():

            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                print("From:", email_from)

                print("Email To:", email_to)
                print("date:", local_message_date)
                print("Subject:", subject)
                print("body:", body.decode('utf-8'))

                '''If subject have "Consent" it will send specific email to recipient'''
                if "Consent" in subject:
                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.starttls()
                    server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)

                    msg = "ALERT NOTICE!"
                    server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                    server.quit()
                else:
                    print("no email");

            else:
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Doing checks on the same line

```
if ("Emergency" in subject) and ("Alert" in email_message):
   ***your logic goes here***
```

**Solution 2:** Using Modularized checks

```
def subject_check(subject):
   if "Emergency" in subject:
       ***logic**
   elif <some_check> :
       ***logic***
   else:
       ***logic***
```

Create separate functions for other checks, so that you can reuse the check logic somewhere else too.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, actually what I'm doing is letting user to entered their own value or condition to be parse. So I couldn't estimate what is the exact value of the parameter that they want to filter. If you're interested you can look at my prefer question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615009/how-to-dynamically-add-an-if-else-statement-in-python)

Comment: I posted my answer to that question too, please check it out.