# Cannot send array list from JavaScript to Django View

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, django

I have an array called `tableData`. But whenever I execute it I couldn't get the result on my python terminal. Since i already put `print(pieFact)`, it should print me the output right? Other than that, when i put `var data = {'test': '2', csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'};`, i actually can get the `2` output in my terminal but not my array when I put `'test': tableData`. Can anyone guide me what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks

URL

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='home-page'),
    path('send/', views.send, name='test'),

]
```

Javascript

```
<script>
//declare the array as a global
var tableData = [];
var URL="{% url 'test' %}"

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").on("click", function () {
    para = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
    condi = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
    value2match = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;

    if (para && condi && value2match !== null) {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

      cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Parameter").value;
      cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Condition").value;
      cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value;
      cell4.innerHTML =
        '<button  class = "del_img "onClick="delSpec(this)"><img src="deleteimg.png" width="30" height="30"></button> </div>';

      var myTab = document.getElementById("myTable");

      // Only add the new row:
      tableData.push([
        document.getElementById("Parameter").value,
        document.getElementById("Condition").value,
        document.getElementById("valuetomatch").value
      ]);

      modal.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      alert("All the input box cannot be empty!");
    }
  });

document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").onclick = function () {
        alert(tableData);
        var data = {'test': '2', csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'};
        $.post(URL, data);

      };
});
</script>
```

View.py

```
def send(request):
    arr = request.POST.get('test')
    print(type(arr))
    print(arr)
    return render(request, 'DemoApp/hi.html')
```

It always returning `None`

[image]

Comment: Is is normal that your variable is printed after the get request and after the post request in your terminal output?

Comment: Also could you please provide your url setup?

Comment: @blondelg yes it cause no issue. Since I can get the `2` output when I change the tableData to `2` . i already update the URL setup above. tq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an issue passing a javascript array object to the request,

maybe try to convert it to json before passing it to the post request:

```js
var tableDataJson = JSON.stringify(tableData);
```

Comment: I just figure out and fix it before your comment haha. But still thank you for your respond !

Comment: Answer are always comming after posting in SO, thanks for upvote anyway.

Comment: Currently im getting my value as `['[["Subject","Equals","test"],["Text","Contain","Testing 1 2 3"]]']`. Do you know how can I make it as  `{[1, 2, 3],  [4, 5, 6]}` ? So that i can count how many value inside the json with `len(arr)`

Comment: This is what you get on server side?

Comment: yes. Actually what im trying to do is an email ingestion function. If you're interested you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615009/how-to-dynamically-add-an-if-else-statement-in-python/67670249?noredirect=1#comment119765960_67670249)

Comment: I need to spend a bit more time on this topic but I think you may have a look at what is sent on a front side to receive what expected on the server side. Do you have a print of `tableData`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233119/discussion-between-blondelg-and-albert-lim).

Answer (score 0):

So I figure out that I need to change my array `tableData` to json first before sending it.
I solved it by using `JSON.stringify(tableData)`.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").onclick = function () {
        alert(tableData);

        var data = {'data[]': JSON.stringify(tableData), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'};
        $.post(URL, data);



      };
});
```

View.py

```
def send(request):
    
    arr = request.POST.getlist('data[]', None)
    print(type(arr))
    print(arr)
    return render(request, 'DemoApp/hi.html')
```